# Is it possible to use VSTS Release functionality without have to store the code in VSTS

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I use perforce and jenkins and would like to use only VSTS Release functionality. Is this possible? Is it a must that code must be stored in VSTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The release could have no artifacts and you can queue Jenkins job by using [Jenkins Queue Job](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/build/jenkins-queue-job) task. Also there is Jenkins Download Artifacts task in Utility category.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at it. But suppose after build I move the compiled code(zipped) to a blob storage. Is these a way for VSTS take that and used it for the release?

Comment: @kumar Yes, you could [download blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-nodejs-how-to-use-blob-storage#download-blobs) through scripts (e.g. NodeJS, .NET etc...), could be run through Command Line task or [custom build/release task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-build-task).